# Why doesn't this OpenGL example draw the triangle?

Tags: haskell, opengl

I'm trying to get a basic "draw a triangle on the screen" [example](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle) working, but in Haskell with the gl and GLFW-b packages.

My code is [here](https://github.com/Lokathor/learnopengl/blob/7c6a2335affaaf5a01a9eceab9806f980ef05778/app/Lesson02.hs):

```
-- https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

-- stuff from base
import Control.Monad (when, mapM)
import Foreign -- includes Ptr and Marshal, among other things.

-- we qualify these names so we can tell what's from GLFW
import qualified Graphics.UI.GLFW as GLFW

-- gl funcs all already have "gl" in their name
import Graphics.GL

width = 800 :: Int

height = 600 :: Int

vertexShaderSource = [
    "#version 330 core\n",
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n",
    "void main()\n",
    "{\n",
    "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n",
    "}\n"]

fragmentShaderSource = [
    "#version 330 core\n",
    "out vec4 color;\n",
    "void main()\n",
    "{\n",
    "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n",
    "}\n"]

getSrcPointer :: [String] -> IO (Ptr (Ptr GLchar), Ptr GLint)
getSrcPointer sourceLines = do
    let glcharLines = map (map (fromIntegral.fromEnum)) sourceLines
    let linesLengths = map (fromIntegral.length) glcharLines
    linesPtrs <- mapM newArray glcharLines
    linesPtrsPtr <- newArray linesPtrs
    lengthsPtr <- newArray linesLengths
    return (linesPtrsPtr,lengthsPtr)

-- type KeyCallback = Window -> Key -> Int -> KeyState -> ModifierKeys -> IO ()
callback :: GLFW.KeyCallback
callback window key scanCode keyState modKeys = do
    putStrLn (show key)
    when (key == GLFW.Key'Escape && keyState == GLFW.KeyState'Pressed)
        (GLFW.setWindowShouldClose window True)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- init GLFW and set the appropriate options
    _ <- GLFW.init
    GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMajor 3)
    GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMinor 3)
    GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'OpenGLProfile GLFW.OpenGLProfile'Core)
    GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'Resizable False)
    -- create our window
    maybeWindow <- GLFW.createWindow width height "Lesson 02" Nothing Nothing
    case maybeWindow of
        Nothing -> do
            -- somehow we failed. Nothing to do but report that and quit.
            putStrLn "Failed to create a GLFW window!"
            GLFW.terminate
        Just window -> do
            -- set our context and callback
            GLFW.makeContextCurrent (Just window)
            GLFW.setKeyCallback window (Just callback)

            -- define the viewport dimensions
            (frameWidth,frameHeight) <- GLFW.getFramebufferSize window
            glViewport 0 0 (fromIntegral frameWidth) (fromIntegral frameHeight)

            -- build and compile our shader program.
            successP <- malloc

            -- vertex shader
            vertexShader <- glCreateShader GL_VERTEX_SHADER
            (linesPtrsPtr,lengthsPtr) <- getSrcPointer vertexShaderSource
            glShaderSource vertexShader 1 linesPtrsPtr lengthsPtr
            glCompileShader vertexShader
            -- check for compilation errors
            glGetShaderiv vertexShader GL_COMPILE_STATUS successP
            success <- peek successP
            when (success == 0) $ do
                putStrLn "Vertex Shader Compile Error:"
                let infoLength = 512
                resultP <- malloc
                infoLog <- mallocArray (fromIntegral infoLength)
                glGetShaderInfoLog vertexShader (fromIntegral infoLength) resultP infoLog
                result <- fromIntegral <$> peek resultP
                logBytes <- peekArray result infoLog
                putStrLn (map (toEnum.fromEnum) logBytes)

            -- fragment shader
            fragmentShader <- glCreateShader GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
            (linesPtrsPtr,lengthsPtr) <- getSrcPointer fragmentShaderSource
            glShaderSource fragmentShader 1 linesPtrsPtr lengthsPtr
            glCompileShader fragmentShader
            -- check for compilation errors
            glGetShaderiv fragmentShader GL_COMPILE_STATUS successP
            success <- peek successP
            when (success == 0) $ do
                putStrLn "Fragment Shader Compile Error:"
                let infoLength = 512
                resultP <- malloc
                infoLog <- mallocArray (fromIntegral infoLength)
                glGetShaderInfoLog fragmentShader (fromIntegral infoLength) resultP infoLog
                result <- fromIntegral <$> peek resultP
                logBytes <- peekArray result infoLog
                putStrLn (map (toEnum.fromEnum) logBytes)

            -- link up the shaders
            shaderProgram <- glCreateProgram
            glAttachShader shaderProgram vertexShader
            glAttachShader shaderProgram fragmentShader
            glLinkProgram shaderProgram
            -- check for linking errors
            glGetProgramiv shaderProgram GL_LINK_STATUS successP
            success <- peek successP
            when (success == 0) $ do
                putStrLn "Program Linking Error:"
                let infoLength = 512
                resultP <- malloc
                infoLog <- mallocArray (fromIntegral infoLength)
                glGetProgramInfoLog shaderProgram (fromIntegral infoLength) resultP infoLog
                result <- fromIntegral <$> peek resultP
                logBytes <- peekArray result infoLog
                putStrLn (map (toEnum.fromEnum) logBytes)

            -- cleanup the sub-programs now that our complete shader program is ready
            glDeleteShader vertexShader
            glDeleteShader fragmentShader

            -- setup vertex data and attribute pointers
            verticesP <- newArray ([
                -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, -- Left  
                0.5, -0.5, 0.0, -- Right 
                0.0,  0.5, 0.0  -- Top
                ] :: [GLfloat])
            let verticesSize = fromIntegral $ sizeOf (0.0 :: GLfloat) * 9
            vboP <- malloc :: IO (Ptr GLuint)
            vaoP <- malloc :: IO (Ptr GLuint)
            glGenVertexArrays 1 vaoP
            glGenBuffers 1 vboP
            -- Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
            vao <- peek vaoP
            glBindVertexArray vao
            vbo <- peek vboP
            glBindBuffer GL_ARRAY_BUFFER vbo
            glBufferData GL_ARRAY_BUFFER verticesSize (castPtr verticesP) GL_STATIC_DRAW
            let threeFloats = fromIntegral $ sizeOf (0.0::GLfloat) * 3
            glVertexAttribPointer 0 3 GL_FLOAT GL_FALSE threeFloats nullPtr
            glEnableVertexAttribArray 0
            -- Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer
            -- registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so
            -- afterwards we can safely unbind
            glBindBuffer GL_ARRAY_BUFFER 0
            -- Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array
            -- to prevent strange bugs)
            glBindVertexArray 0

            -- "game loop"
            let loop :: IO ()
                loop = do
                    shouldClose <- GLFW.windowShouldClose window
                    if shouldClose
                        then return ()
                        else do
                            -- event poll
                            GLFW.pollEvents

                            -- clear the screen
                            glClearColor 0.2 0.3 0.3 1.0
                            glClear GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT
                            -- draw a triangle
                            glUseProgram shaderProgram
                            glBindVertexArray vao
                            glDrawArrays GL_TRIANGLES 0 3
                            glBindVertexArray 0

                            -- swap buffers and go again
                            GLFW.swapBuffers window
                            loop
            loop

            -- clean up the gl resources
            glDeleteVertexArrays 1 vaoP
            glDeleteBuffers 1 vboP
            -- clean up the GLFW resources
            GLFW.terminate
```

It compiles and runs without any reported errors, but it only shows the clear color; the triangle isn't drawn at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when I compile and run your program, I get shader compile and program link errors.  Specifically, I get errors:

```
Vertex Shader Compile Error:
0:1(18): error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Fragment Shader Compile Error:
0:1(18): error: syntax error, unexpected $end
```

and there are link errors too, of course.

On closer inspection, your `glShaderSource` calls are flawed.  Though they are passing arrays of line pointers and line lengths for six lines per shader, the line count argument is `1`.  If I modify the last line of `getSrcPointer` to return the line count:

```
return (linesPtrsPtr,lengthsPtr, (fromIntegral.length) linesLengths)
```

and then pass this count to the `glShaderSource` calls in each case:

```
(linesPtrsPtr,lengthsPtr,count) <- getSrcPointer vertexShaderSource
glShaderSource vertexShader count linesPtrsPtr lengthsPtr
...
(linesPtrsPtr,lengthsPtr,count) <- getSrcPointer fragmentShaderSource
glShaderSource fragmentShader count linesPtrsPtr lengthsPtr
```

then your program works fine.

Happy triangling!

Comment: How very strange. I got shader compile/link errors at first and then they went away with revisions but I kept not seeing the triangle. Some sort of  difference in how the driver reports errors perhaps? I figured it had to be something I did when trying to convert C to Haskell, but this is also my first time using anything from Foreign so I wasn't clear where things had gone off the rails.

Comment: The whole "splitting the shader source into lines" business is messed up anyway. Just pass it as one single long string. `glShaderSource` being able to take multiple source strings that are concatenated internally is to allow for easy reuse of shader building blocks that are required throughout multiple source. Like for example if one has a certain set of uniforms that are to be specified for vertex and fragment shaders or in multiple shaders.

Comment: Yeah I've never really used C++, and it was unclear how those literals were being shoved directly together. I'll simplify it down to "getSrcPointers :: String -> IO (Ptr (Ptr GLchar), Ptr GLint)" for now, and I can make it process a [String] later when I need to. Seems like there's going to be a lot of small places to make the whole gl process more ergonomic.

Comment: I'll add this: `"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n",`
You don't need the `f` to denote floating point number in a shader. They use single precision by default.